# How can I delete a document with all its subcollections in firebase with flutter and dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

Every time I try to delete a document programmatically using documentSnapshot.delete(), the firebase only deletes the document and not its subcollections. I want to permanently delete a document and all its subcollections with the push of a button and every time the user tries to create the same document, it'd be empty.

What's the proper way to do that?

**(CLOSED)**

This is the code that worked for me:

```
CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection name').doc('document name').collection('collection name');
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> documentReference = collectionReference.doc('document name');

documentReference.collection('lists').get().then((lists) {
    lists.docs.forEach((listElement) {
      documentReference.collection('lists').doc(listElement.id.toString()).collection('cards').get().then((cards) {
        cards.docs.forEach((cardElement) {
          documentReference.collection('lists').doc(listElement.id.toString()).collection('cards').doc(cardElement.id.toString()).delete();
        });
      });
      documentReference.collection('lists').doc(listElement.id.toString()).delete();
    });
  });

await documentReference.delete();
```

Comment: What is the code that you are using?

Comment: @bharats I set a collectionReference variable to be equal to collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('boards').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).collection('boards');

then I set a documentReference to be equal to DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> documentReference = collectionReference.doc(thisSpecificBoardName);

Then I have the command documentReference.delete()

Comment: If using a cloud function for that is an option for you, [check this out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

Answer (score 2):

> Deleting a `document` does not automatically delete all documents in its sub-collections.

There is no method in firestore API to delete subcollections along with the document. You need to loop through and delete the documents in subcollections and then delete the parent `document`.

Here's a [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#:%7E:text=When%20you%20delete,see%20Delete%20Collections.) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Dart but here's my simple solution with PHP Firestore;

```php
public function destroyCollection(CollectionReference $collection)
{
    $documents = [];
    foreach ($collection->listDocuments() as $document) {
        $documents[] = $document;
    }

    $this->destroyDocuments($documents);
}

/**
 * @param DocumentReference[] $documents
 */
public function destroyDocuments(array $documents)
{
    if (!$documents) return;
    
    $batch = $this->database->getBatch();
    foreach ($documents as $document) {
        $batch->delete($document);

        foreach ($document->collections() as $collection) {
            $this->destroyCollection($collection);
        }
    }
    
    $batch->commit();
}
```

It'll delete all the documents that it finds no matter how deeply nested they are. And non-existing docs won't show up in snapshots and queries so that's why I'm using the `listDocuments()` method even tho I'm sacrificing performance a bit.